# UITableView with UIDatePicker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uidatepicker

please I need some advice about design approaches in iPhone programming.
I want to display a table view (with three cells that will never change) and a *UIDatePicker*.
I don't use Interface Builder.

I created a *UIViewController* subclass and tried to put all together in its *viewDidLoad* method:

```
UITableView *myView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 250) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
[self.view addSubview:myView];

datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 320, 216)];`
```

and other initialization params...

```
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];
```

I miss something, I don't understand how to add *UITableViewCell* objects to *myView*?

I'm all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add it in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method in the UITableViewDataSource protocol.  See the example here: http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-unique-looking-tables-with-custom-cells.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as jeremie stated you need to add the some UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods to get a UITableView fully functional.